# Get the name of caller (or method) that created the WCF Service instance?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with a private constructor. If I'm not wrong, constructors must be parameterless in WCF and the parameter I need is the caller's name (or caller's method name), so I can assign a few readonly fields.

Is there a way that I can get the caller's name -- or the method that invoked it? I was playing around with OperationContext.Current, but without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend accessing the stack trace for performance reasons.

WCF service constructors only need to be parameterless if you are using the default [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory(loband).aspx). You can specify a custom service factory in your .svc file like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
   Service="Namespace.To.Service"
   Factory="Namespace.To.ServiceFactory" %>
```

The process to creating your class in a custom way goes like this:

1. Your [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory(loband).aspx) creates an instance of your custom [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) in CreateServiceHost
2. ServiceHost overrides [OnOpening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.onopening(loband).aspx) and adds a custom [IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior(loband).aspx) to Description.[Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription.behaviors(loband).aspx) (Description is a property on the base class)
3. Your IServiceBehavior implements [ApplyDispatchBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.applydispatchbehavior(loband).aspx) and enumerates serviceHostBase.[ChannelDispatchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostbase.channeldispatchers(loband).aspx), checking if each is a [ChannelDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.channeldispatcher(loband).aspx).

   - Each ChannelDispatcher's [Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.channeldispatcher.endpoints(loband).aspx) property is enumerated and it's DispatchRuntime.[InstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.instanceprovider(loband).aspx) is changed to a custom [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider(loband).aspx)
4. The custom IInstanceProvider creates the instance in [GetInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587089(loband).aspx)

I have used this to delegate creation to an IoC container.

Comment: thank you very much, are there any more detailed guides i could look?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx.

Comment: The reference to "ServiceHostFactory" in my answer links to the documentation, which includes an example.

Comment: though, i dont have a config file, since im hosting my service through an console application -- serviceHost=new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:1234"));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISubscribe), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "");
serviceHost.Open(); -- i'll probably figure it out, but if you have any advice on how to set it up quickly, let me know ;)

Comment: Updated answer to include the steps involved. In your case, you'd skip the ServiceHostFactory and use your custom ServiceHost directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the .NET call stack like this:

```
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
var frame = trace.GetFrame( 1 ); // Frame 0 is current function
var callingMethodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
```

I do not know whether this technique works in your situation, but you could give it a try.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help :( if i access all frames from 0, i get these:

.ctor
CreateService
GetInstance
GetInstance
GetServiceInstance
ProcessMessage5
ProcessMessage4
ProcessMessage3
ProcessMessage2
ProcessMessage1
Process
Dispatch
DispatchAndReleasePump
HandleRequest
AsyncMessagePump
OnAsyncReceiveComplete
UnhandledExceptionFrame
Complete
OnReceive
UnhandledExceptionFrame
Complete
OnReceiveComplete
OnAsyncReadComplete
FinishRead
AsyncReadCallback
CompleteCallback
UnhandledExceptionFrame
PerformIOCompletionCallback

--

except the (.ctor) constructor, those are all auto-generated by wcf

Comment: I would be shocked if the WCF service has visibility to the call stack on another system.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a valid case for the called method to do something different based on the identity of the caller. If the caller's identity matters, then the caller should pass into the called method whatever information it needs. Instead of:

```
public MyClass(string callerName) {
    if (callerName == "Caller1")
        _field = "Value1";
    else
        _field = "Value2";
}
```

use

```
public MyClass(string value) {
    _field = value;
}
```

Comment: i would like to pass the neccesarry values, but constructors in wcf services must be parameterless.

Comment: See below for the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to either break your service down to multiple similar services (yuk) or break out your method(s) to be overloads intended for different callers to use.

i.e. if you have Service1 which provides method foo() to CallerA and CallerB, maybe try making foo private, and exposing fooA() and fooB(), which are exclusively called by CallerA and CallerB, respectively. Then fooA() and fooB() can set the readonly properties appropriately before calling foo().